# I want to click the button using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
music_tracks = soup.find_all('music-text-row')

for music_track in music_tracks:
            print(music_track)
            Track_Name = music_track['primary-text']
            popularity_bar = music_track.find('music-popularity-bar')
            Popularity = popularity_bar['rating'] if popularity_bar else None
            print(Track_Name)

            more_button = music_track.find_all('music-button')[-1]
            final_cl = more_button.find('button')
            print(final_cl)
            final_cl.click()

 final_cl = more_button.find('button').click()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I want to click on final_cl.click()

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Or whichever browser you're using

# Assuming you have navigated to the desired page using driver.get('your_page_url')

# Find all elements that match the 'music-button' class or any specific identifier your buttons have
music_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'music-button')  # Adjust the selector as needed

# If you're trying to click the last 'music-button' of a specific music track
if music_buttons:
    # Find the 'button' element within the last 'music-button'. Adjust the selector if necessary
    # This assumes that the structure is consistent and the button you want to click is within the 'music-button' element
    final_button = music_buttons[-1].find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
    if final_button:
        final_button.click()  # This will click the button
    else:
        print("Button element not found within the music-button.")
else:
    print("No music-button elements found.")
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is that you are finding the button and then clicking it, if the button does not exist the find returns null.
To fix this issue you just need to wait until the value of final_cl is not none.

```
import time
music_tracks = soup.find_all('music-text-row')

for music_track in music_tracks:
print(music_track)
Track_Name = music_track['primary-text']
popularity_bar = music_track.find('music-popularity-bar')
Popularity = popularity_bar['rating'] if popularity_bar else None
print(Track_Name)

more_buttons = music_track.find_all('music-button')
if more_buttons:
    final_button = more_buttons[-1]
    final_cl = final_button.find('button')
    attempts = 0
    max_attempts = 5  # Maximum number of attempts
    while final_cl is None and attempts < max_attempts:
        print("Final button not found. Retrying...")
        time.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before retrying
        final_button = more_buttons[-1]
        final_cl = final_button.find('button')
        attempts += 1

    if final_cl:
        print(final_cl)
        final_cl.click()
    else:
        print("Final button not found after {} attempts.".format(max_attempts))
else:
    print("No more buttons found.")
```

What do we do here?

we recursively look for the button, if it is not found.
adust the time according to your needs

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12410/what-to-do-when-waiting-for-an-element-to-appear-isnt-enough
here is a similar problem yo yours , it was asked on SQA and a similar solution.